Distribute Coins in Binary Tree
I am looking at solutions for LeetCode problem 979. Distribute Coins in Binary Tree:

You are given the root of a binary tree with n nodes where each node in the tree has node.val coins. There are n coins in total throughout the whole tree.
In one move, we may choose two adjacent nodes and move one coin from one node to another. A move may be from parent to child, or from child to parent.
Return the minimum number of moves required to make every node have exactly one coin.

I am analysing the C++ solution of votrubac
int traverse(TreeNode* r, int &moves) {
  if (r == nullptr) return 0;
  int left = traverse(r->left, moves), right = traverse(r->right, moves);
  moves += abs(left) + abs(right); // <----- do not understand
  return r->val + left + right - 1;
}
int distributeCoins(TreeNode* r, int moves = 0) {
  traverse(r, moves);
  return moves;
}

I have hard time to understand that:

why move = move + abs(left) + abs(right) in the current subtree?
why we don't involve curr_node? e.g move = move + abs(curr_node) + abs(left) + abs(right)?
does it mean in each sub tree the move abs(left) + abs(right) equals the moves of the left subtree and the right subtree only?
in the top root subtree, we have move = abs(left) + abs(right), so there is no move for the root node? Looks like abs(left) OR abs(right) cover the move of root node?


@user24714692, if involve curr node will create 2 ops, then why just move = abs(left) + abs(right)?

@user24714692, my problem is not about move = move + xxxx. My problem is that each subtree we say sub move = abs(left) + abs(right) without involve current node.  in final root, total move = sub abs(left) + sub abs(right). you can see that abs(left) or abs(right) cover the operation of root node operation e.g. root 0 -> left 3 -> right 0. It is 3 op; move = left abs(2) + right abs(1); you can see that left cover the op of root node. Basically in final root op, left right auto cover the root node. the question is that why we don't need to consider curr node of the count of moves entire travel

That's a simple question. Why don't you involve the current node and see what happens? Note that the goal is to only count the moves needed to distribute coins between nodes to ensure each node ends up with exactly one coin. Also note that this is a common technique "not to involve the current node". It is used in max path sum and several other problems, similarly.

@trincot sorry forgot

Let's first describe the meaning of the involved variables:
Meaning of the variables
The variable left represents the number of coins that are too many in the left subtree, i.e. that need to be moved out of that subtree via the edge between the current node and its left child. If this number is negative, then it represents the number of coins that are missing in this subtree, i.e. that need to be moved into that subtree via that edge.
right has a similar meaning, but then for the right subtree.
moves is a single integer, shared by all execution contexts, of traverse that represents the number of needed moves so far. It makes no distinction between "upward" or "downward" moves.
With that information we can address your doubts:
Clarifications

why move = move + abs(left) + abs(right) in the current subtree?

This assignment to moves takes into account the number of coins that need to traverse along two specific edges: the edge between the current node and its left child, and the edge between the current node and its right child.
left represents the number of coins that need to traverse upward from the current node's left child to the current node. This represents a number of moves that will occur using the edge to the current node's left child. If left is negative, that value still represents a number of moves, but they are just going to happen in the opposite direction. For counting the number of moves, the direction is not relevant, so we take the absolute value.
Therefore abs(left) represents the number of moves via one specific edge -- the one between the current node and its left child -- and abs(right) represents the same for the other child edge. By accumulating this sum to move we get the number of moves along all edges below the current node, and so when we arrive at the root, we will eventually account for the moves that will occur via all edges.

why we don't involve curr_node? e.g move = move + abs(curr_node) + abs(left) + abs(right)?

As we know there are just as many coins in the tree as there are nodes, we have enough information if we know how many nodes are lacking or are in excess in the node's subtrees.
Take an example: Let's say we know that 5 coins are missing in the node's left subtree (left is -5) and there are 2 coins too many in its right subtree (right is 2). Now it doesn't matter how many coins there are in the current node to decide how many coins have to move in/out to/from the subtrees. If in this example the current node happens to be the root, then we know "without looking" that the current node must have 4 coins: 1 for itself, and 2 coins will have to bubble up from the right subtree, and 5 coins (3 it already had, and 2 it got from the right) that need to move into its left subtree.
If the current node is not the root, then if it has more than 4 coins, then still we would have the same moves involving its two children, while the excess will have to move up later via the edge to the node's parent. But that edge is out of scope for dealing with the current node. The algorithm deals with that when visiting its parent.
Similarly if the current node would have less than 4 coins, then that shortage will be filled later, again when we visit its parent.
In short, moves is increased here with a value that reflects the number of moves via its two child edges, not the ones that are needed to transfer coins via its parent edge. And since we know the total number of coins, we don't need to know how many coins the current node holds to determine how many moves will happen via its two child edges.

does it mean in each sub tree the move abs(left) + abs(right) equals the moves of the left subtree and the right subtree only?

abs(left) + abs(right) represents the number of coins that need to traverse the two child edges of the current node, and only those. Moves of coins along deeper edges in those subtrees were already added to moves.

in the top root subtree, we have move = abs(left) + abs(right), so there is no move for the root node? Looks like abs(left) OR abs(right) cover the move of root node?

Just a minor correction. The code has +=, not =. When this assignment happens, move will already have accumulated counts from deeper edges in the tree. They should not be lost, and so += is needed.
The above clarifications should answer this doubt too. If left is negative, then this represents the number of coins that move from the root node to its left child via that edge to the child. As this is the root node, such a scenario would imply that coins are available for these moves (into the left subtree): using excess coins in the root node itself and/or excess coins in the root's right subtree.
If for instance there are not enough coins in the root node itself to cover for these moves to the left child, then surely right will be strictly positive and match what is needed: that number represents the number of coins that will move upward along the edge from the root's right child to the root.
I hope this clarifies it.
